# How to write in a scientific way?

Tags: writing-style, technology

Could anybody help me in rephrasing these sentences in a scientific way?

> Both d1 and d2 perform well under sparse vegetation (LAI<1), for LAI larger than 1, d1 (with almost constant performances up to LAI =6 ) outperforms d2 (performances decreased quickly with increased LAI)

Comment: I think it would be better to rephrase them in a comprehensible way. You could do that by breaking this into two sentences, putting in the word "and" where needed, and using fewer parentheses.

Comment: Any ideas from your side pleas?

Comment: LAI<1 implies sparse vegetation, and you've already defined it? Then "Both d1 and d2 perform well when LAI<1. d1 performance is nearly constant for LAI <= 6, while d2 performance declines rapidly with increasing LAI."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Both d1 and d2 perform well under sparse vegetation where LAI<1.
>
> Where LAI>1, d1 outperforms d2: d1 has almost constant performances up
>   to LAI =6, whereas d2 performance decreases quickly with increased
>   LAI.

You could substitute *is less than* or *is greater than* for < and > if preferred. I've stuck to the same terminology as I can't change that without know ing more about the nature of the experiment. I've also used a colon in the 2nd sentence to skirt the issue of whether d1 should be D1 to start a sentence!

Answer (score 0):

> Both d1 and d2 perform well with sparse vegetation (LAI < 1).   For 1
>   < LAI < 6, 
>   d1 outperforms d2:  d1 shows little change in performance up
>   to LAI =6, whereas the performance of d2 decreases quickly with
>   increased LAI.

I've tried to put the d1 at the end of the first line onto the second for reasons of style, and to leave a gap after the colon to avoid confusion with ratio style, but the autoformat thinks it's smart enough to decide for me.

Answer (score 0):

With a left curly brace for the 3 last lines of the following block and the proper symbols, I'd say something like this:

```
let p(x) be the performance of x and LAI the coefficient of vegetation sparsity,
p(d1) ≈ p(d2) > 0   LAI < 1
p(d1) > p(d2)       1 < LAI < 6
p(d1) ≈ p(d2) ≈ 0   6 < LAI
```